# How to change the position of the cursor in "centered-cursor-mode" in Emacs?

Tags: emacs, elisp

I am using [centered-cursor-mode](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/centered-cursor-mode.el) in Emacs, and I really like it. It has been bothering me a lot, though, that the position of the cursor is set lower than the center, and I would actually prefer it to be higher than the center.

Every few months I get annoyed enough to try and do something about it, but I have so far been unsuccessful. My impression was that the answer was to change the numbers in this bit

```
(defcustom ccm-vpos-init '(round (window-text-height) 2)
  "This is the screen line position where the cursor initially stays."
  :group 'centered-cursor
  :tag "Vertical cursor position"
  :type '(choice (const :tag "Center" (round (window-text-height) 2))
                 (const :tag "Golden ratio" (round (* 21 (window-text-height)) 34)) 
                 (integer :tag "Lines from top" :value 10)))
(make-variable-buffer-local 'ccm-vpos-init)
```

but it doesn't seem like it.

Does anyone know how to change the centering position of the cursor in "centered-cursor-mode.el"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can adjust the line position in the current buffer with <kbd>M-C-+</kbd> and <kbd>M-C--</kbd>. The prefix argument specifies how many lines you want to move the cursor, so e.g. if you want to have the cursor two lines higher, you would type:

<kbd>C-u 2 C-M-+</kbd>

For a more permanent solution, you can also customize the entry of the "Vertical cursor position" (aka `ccm-vpos-init`) as your question already suggests. Accessing that entry via <kbd>M-x customize-group RET centered-cursor RET</kbd> you'll find three basic options:

- Centered (default)
- Golden ratio
- Lines from the top

IMHO the third option only makes sense if you always use the exact same window size (so horizontal split windows will be a problem) while the second point could perhaps be an option for you?

However, you can very easily add a forth option to the definition of `ccm-vpos-init` that allows you to position the cursor exactly where you want it, for instance:

```
(defcustom ccm-vpos-init '(round (window-text-height) 2)
  "This is the screen line position where the cursor initially stays."
  :group 'centered-cursor
  :tag "Vertical cursor position"
  :type '(choice (const :tag "Center" (round (window-text-height) 2))
                 (const :tag "Golden ratio" (round (* 21 (window-text-height)) 34))
                 (integer :tag "Lines from top" :value 10)
                 (const :tag "2 Lines above center" (- (round (window-text-height) 2) 2))))
```

The next time you start Emacs, this forth option will be available in the "Vertical cursor position" entry described above.

Comment: Oh, my, that was perfect!! I was so keen on a key binding to adjust the line position, but had no idea it existed! I am quite happy with the "Lines from the top" option since I always have just one window open, and use the same computer. 10 lines was perfect, too. Many thanks!

Comment: Is there a way to change this in my .emacs file instead of through M-x customize-group?

Comment: @Vivi -- Hi, Vivi, nice to see you again ;-) When you use `M-x customize-group`, your customizations usually *are* stored at the bottom of your `.emacs` file, unless you specified a different file (e.g. `(setq custom-file "~/.emacs-custom.el")`). If you don't like the customization system, look for lisp code that starts with `(custom-set-variables ...)` followed by some lines of the form `'(...)`. Cut the line referring to `ccm-vpos-init` and paste it into your .emacs file. Remove the single quote at the beginning and insert `setq` after the left parenthesis, i.e., `(setq ccm-vpos-init ...)`.

Comment: Thanks, @Thomas. I am moving from Aquamacs to Emacs hence the confusion. Aquamacs stores customisation a in its own initialisation file, and I didn't know I could just copy that code and reuse it. Emacs writes it in my .emacs file! One more reason to tidy up my .emacs :) thanks again for the help, much appreciated.

Comment: I would also appreciate a solution that doesn't involve `customize group`

Comment: @WickedJargon What would you prefer instead?

Comment: @Thomas. I attempted following your instructions, but the after doing `M-x customize-group RET centered-cursor RET`, I do not see the options you've listed. What I was asking for was, a piece of code I could use in my initialization file isntead of using the options. Do you by chance have the `custom.el` code you mentioned in the comment above?

Comment: Did you try the following? Type `C-h v` and then `ccm-vpos-init`. In the popup window, there should be a link in the first line that takes you to the existing `(defcustom ccm-vpos-init ...` definition. Comment that one out, and insert the one from my answer instead. After restarting Emacs, the options should be available to you for customizing.

Comment: Thanks! My only remaining question is, how do I modify your code to change it from 2 to say 3 lines above center?

Comment: The very last `2` in the code snippet above specifies the number of lines above center. Change that to `3`, then restart Emacs. You might have to select some other option first, and then go back to the last one in order for it to take effect.